# Sort C# list with objects from another list

Tags: c#, .net

Have two classes:

```
public class Object1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And have:

```
List<Object1> A;
List<Object2> B;
```

Need to sort elements of list `A` by `Prop1` same way as they already sorted in list `B` with `Prop2`. `Prop1` and `Prop2` have repetitions and i can't remove duplicates in my solution. So I must sort list `A` like this:

1. First goes objects of list A with Prop1 same as objects of list B ordered by Prop2 in list B (list B has already ordered)
2. Then goes objects of list A with Prop1 that doesn`t exist in list B with Prop2 property.

Edit `2014/03/13 14:20`

`Prop1` collection is not unique and has repetitions (same as `Prop2`)

Edit `2014/03/13 15:23`

Some example.

I have this:

```
            var A = new List<Object1>
            {
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b_c"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "x_y_z"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b_c"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a"},
            };
        var B = new List<Object2>
            {
                new Object2{Prop2 = "a"},
                new Object2{Prop2 = "a_b"},
                new Object2{Prop2 = "a_b_c"},
            };
```

And expected this after sort:

```
            var expected = new List<Object1>
            {
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b_c"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "a_b_c"},
                new Object1{Prop1 = "x_y_z"},
            };
```

Comment: Do you know the type of sorting? Do you know how list B is sorted? You could use that sorting method again.

Comment: Do you want to sort `A` or their properties `Prop1`. So do you need to order the internal collection or the outer? If the latter, how do you want to sort the outer collection by the inner collection? How are they related? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I have to say, it might not be the best English, but I found it pretty clear what the question was.

Comment: @M.Mimpen This is light example of my work problem. List B sort with Forel algorithm with some extension. So I can`t sort list A with this method. List B contains only usefull objects (usefull by Forel criteria).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ive tried to put easiest example of what I need. Have not the best English but try to explain again. I must sort by Prop1 all elements in list A same way as in list B elements are sorted by Prop2. Prop1=Prop2. But Prop2s in list B is a subset of the Prop1s set in list A.

Comment: @k.makarov: if you have an example (i mean sample data) edit your question and provide it. Then your question might get opened again. It's still not clear how you want to sort the outer collection by a property that is another collection. The only way i could think of is to show first all elements in `A` where at least one string is in any of the elements in `B`'s strings. But that would be just one criterion(contains top, contains not bottom).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have edit my question. Fauled with problem explanation.

Comment: @k.makarov: It is _still_ not clear. What are `2014/03/13 14:20` and `2014/03/13 14:20`? That aren't collections.

Comment: It's also not clear to what object(`Object1` or `Object2`) they belong. And you also have shown only a single object, how should we sort a single object?

Comment: @k.makarov: i see that your last edit also changed the property from collection to string, I'm outty!

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, i was incorrect when explained my problem. Add some example what i expect

Comment: @k.makarov: Now you have changed the question completely and there are many similar questions on SO. However,  the sample data is not so well-chosen since even without the second list the sorted `A`-list would become your desired result. In other words: it seems to be ordered simply by `Prop1`.

Answer (score -1):

You  most probably you have to
look on [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb355408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for shared object types and [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
for second case.

There you can implement custom equality comparer to compare *your* data types.

Answer (score -1):

To sort by the order of another list you can use `Join`. This preserves the order of the outer collection (i.e. `B`) and you can select the elements of the inner collection as the result, i.e. `A`.

```
var sortedA = B.Join (A, b => b.Prop2, a => a.Prop1, (b, a) => a).ToArray();
```

You then need to concatenate the elements of A that do not exist in the sorted collection.

```
var allA = A.Concat(A.Except(sortedA));
```

Comment: So you "found it pretty clear what the question was"? `Prop1` and `Prop2` are collections not single strings ;-) This does not work at all, it just compiles because the collections will be compared by reference which is not what OP wants.

Comment: but what if Prop2 and Prop1 not all unique? Prop1 collection may have repeats. And Prop2 may have repeats. In case of my work solution I can`t delete repeats from Prop1 and Prop2

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Prop1` and `Prop2` are strings. `public string Prop1 { get; set; }` I'm not sure what you're saying?

Comment: @TimSchmelter See what you're saying. That was a lucky assumption on my part! ;-) This is a moving target.

Comment: @TimRogers sorry for change. Moving target - best explain for this task :)